# Checking Permissions of components of a path in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a path to a file with multiple `/` characters separating the path components. Is there any way I can check the permissions of each directory and the file with `<std::path::Components as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next`?

Comment: Have you read the [chapter on iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html) in the rust book? After reading that you might want to check out the [`all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) iterator method.

Comment: @harmic I was looking for a conceptual picture rather. I looked up https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Components.html which states that `std::path::Components` is an iterator over the components of a path. To me it seems that `std::path::Components` are the components over which the iteration is defined and the function (method) `next` returns the next component in the path each time. Is that a correct picture?

Comment: Yes, for any iterator, calling `next` yields the next element. However you rarely call that directly, normally you either use other iterator methods such as `map`, `filter`, `all`, `any` etc - there are many defined there. The first document I linked describes all this.

Answer (score 1):

Path components aren't `Path`s themselves. You are likely looking for [`std::path::Path.ancestors()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.ancestors). You can iterate over those and check their `metadata()?.permissions().mode()` as you like.